# updating to ARC errors

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to update a project to ARC. Though I've seen a few posts on updating to ARC, none of the posts I've seen handle this specific issue. I've got multiple errors, most saying:

```
ARC Issue
Pointer to non-const type 'id' with no explicit ownership
```

pointing to line

```
CCARRAY_FOREACH(children_, item)
```

in the CCMenu.m class. Please help.

**Updated:**

After restarting Xcode the above issue is no longer found at

```
CCARRAY_FOREACH(children_, item)
```

but was found in the ccCArray.h class at the lines I've commented as

```
// Arc Issue
```

Several other errors have surface. 
The warning sign:

```
Arc Issue
Destination for this '_builtin__memmove_chk' call is a pointer to ownership-qualified-type 'autoreleasing-id'
```

appears wherever is memmove called in the code.

another error:

```
ARC Casting Rules
Implicit conversion of C pointer type 'void *' to Objective-C pointer type 'id' requires a bridged cast
```

appears at the lines I've commented as:

```
//ARC Casting Rules
```

ccCArray.h:

```
#ifndef CC_ARRAY_H
#define CC_ARRAY_H

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import <stdlib.h>
#import <string.h>


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark ccArray for Objects

// Easy integration 
#define CCARRAYDATA_FOREACH(__array__, __object__)                                                          \
__object__=__array__->arr[0]; for(NSUInteger i=0, num=__array__->num; i<num; i++,   __object__=__array__->arr[i])   \


typedef struct ccArray {
NSUInteger num, max;
id *arr;   // Arc Issue
} ccArray;

/** Allocates and initializes a new array with specified capacity */
static inline ccArray* ccArrayNew(NSUInteger capacity) {
if (capacity == 0)
    capacity = 1; 

ccArray *arr = (ccArray*)malloc( sizeof(ccArray) );    // Arc Issue
arr->num = 0;
arr->arr =  (id*) malloc( capacity * sizeof(id) );
arr->max = capacity;

return arr;
}

static inline void ccArrayRemoveAllObjects(ccArray *arr);

/** Frees array after removing all remaining objects. Silently ignores nil arr. */
static inline void ccArrayFree(ccArray *arr)
{
if( arr == nil ) return;

ccArrayRemoveAllObjects(arr);

free(arr->arr);
free(arr);
}

/** Doubles array capacity */
static inline void ccArrayDoubleCapacity(ccArray *arr)
{
arr->max *= 2;
id *newArr = (id *)realloc( arr->arr, arr->max * sizeof(id) );    // Arc Issue
// will fail when there's not enough memory
NSCAssert(newArr != NULL, @"ccArrayDoubleCapacity failed. Not enough memory");
arr->arr = newArr;
}

/** Increases array capacity such that max >= num + extra. */
static inline void ccArrayEnsureExtraCapacity(ccArray *arr, NSUInteger extra)
{
while (arr->max < arr->num + extra)
    ccArrayDoubleCapacity(arr);
}

/** shrinks the array so the memory footprint corresponds with the number of items */
static inline void ccArrayShrink(ccArray *arr)
{
    NSUInteger newSize;

 //only resize when necessary
if (arr->max > arr->num && !(arr->num==0 && arr->max==1))
{
    if (arr->num!=0) 
    {
        newSize=arr->num;
        arr->max=arr->num; 
    }
    else 
    {//minimum capacity of 1, with 0 elements the array would be free'd by realloc
        newSize=1;
        arr->max=1;
    }

    arr->arr = (id*) realloc(arr->arr,newSize * sizeof(id) );   // Arc Issue
    NSCAssert(arr->arr!=NULL,@"could not reallocate the memory");
}
} 

/** Returns index of first occurence of object, NSNotFound if object not found. */
static inline NSUInteger ccArrayGetIndexOfObject(ccArray *arr, id object)
{
for( NSUInteger i = 0; i < arr->num; i++)
    if( arr->arr[i] == object ) return i;

return NSNotFound;
}

/** Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether object is present in array. */
static inline BOOL ccArrayContainsObject(ccArray *arr, id object)
{
return ccArrayGetIndexOfObject(arr, object) != NSNotFound;
}

/** Appends an object. Bahaviour undefined if array doesn't have enough capacity. */
static inline void ccArrayAppendObject(ccArray *arr, id object)
{
arr->arr[arr->num] = [object retain];
arr->num++;
}

/** Appends an object. Capacity of arr is increased if needed. */
static inline void ccArrayAppendObjectWithResize(ccArray *arr, id object)
{
ccArrayEnsureExtraCapacity(arr, 1);
ccArrayAppendObject(arr, object);
}

/** Appends objects from plusArr to arr. Behaviour undefined if arr doesn't have
enough capacity. */
static inline void ccArrayAppendArray(ccArray *arr, ccArray *plusArr)
{
for( NSUInteger i = 0; i < plusArr->num; i++)
    ccArrayAppendObject(arr, plusArr->arr[i]);
}

/** Appends objects from plusArr to arr. Capacity of arr is increased if needed. */
static inline void ccArrayAppendArrayWithResize(ccArray *arr, ccArray *plusArr)
{
ccArrayEnsureExtraCapacity(arr, plusArr->num);
ccArrayAppendArray(arr, plusArr);
}

/** Inserts an object at index */
static inline void ccArrayInsertObjectAtIndex(ccArray *arr, id object, NSUInteger index)
{
NSCAssert(index<=arr->num, @"Invalid index. Out of bounds");

ccArrayEnsureExtraCapacity(arr, 1);

NSUInteger remaining = arr->num - index;
if( remaining > 0)
    memmove(&arr->arr[index+1], &arr->arr[index], sizeof(id) * remaining );

arr->arr[index] = [object retain];
arr->num++;
}

/** Swaps two objects */
static inline void ccArraySwapObjectsAtIndexes(ccArray *arr, NSUInteger index1, NSUInteger index2)
{
NSCAssert(index1 < arr->num, @"(1) Invalid index. Out of bounds");
NSCAssert(index2 < arr->num, @"(2) Invalid index. Out of bounds");

id object1 = arr->arr[index1];

arr->arr[index1] = arr->arr[index2];
arr->arr[index2] = object1;
}

/** Removes all objects from arr */
static inline void ccArrayRemoveAllObjects(ccArray *arr)
{
while( arr->num > 0 )
    [arr->arr[--arr->num] release]; 
}

/** Removes object at specified index and pushes back all subsequent objects.
Behaviour undefined if index outside [0, num-1]. */
static inline void ccArrayRemoveObjectAtIndex(ccArray *arr, NSUInteger index)
{
[arr->arr[index] release];
arr->num--;

NSUInteger remaining = arr->num - index;
if(remaining>0)
    memmove(&arr->arr[index], &arr->arr[index+1], remaining * sizeof(id));
}

/** Removes object at specified index and fills the gap with the last object,
thereby avoiding the need to push back subsequent objects.
Behaviour undefined if index outside [0, num-1]. */
static inline void ccArrayFastRemoveObjectAtIndex(ccArray *arr, NSUInteger index)
{
[arr->arr[index] release];
NSUInteger last = --arr->num;
arr->arr[index] = arr->arr[last];
}

static inline void ccArrayFastRemoveObject(ccArray *arr, id object)
{
NSUInteger index = ccArrayGetIndexOfObject(arr, object);
if (index != NSNotFound)
    ccArrayFastRemoveObjectAtIndex(arr, index);
}

/** Searches for the first occurance of object and removes it. If object is not
found the function has no effect. */
static inline void ccArrayRemoveObject(ccArray *arr, id object)
{
NSUInteger index = ccArrayGetIndexOfObject(arr, object);
if (index != NSNotFound)
    ccArrayRemoveObjectAtIndex(arr, index);
}

/** Removes from arr all objects in minusArr. For each object in minusArr, the
first matching instance in arr will be removed. */
static inline void ccArrayRemoveArray(ccArray *arr, ccArray *minusArr)
{
for( NSUInteger i = 0; i < minusArr->num; i++)
    ccArrayRemoveObject(arr, minusArr->arr[i]);
}

/** Removes from arr all objects in minusArr. For each object in minusArr, all
matching instances in arr will be removed. */
static inline void ccArrayFullRemoveArray(ccArray *arr, ccArray *minusArr)
{
NSUInteger back = 0;

for( NSUInteger i = 0; i < arr->num; i++) {
    if( ccArrayContainsObject(minusArr, arr->arr[i]) ) {
        [arr->arr[i] release];
        back++;
    } else
        arr->arr[i - back] = arr->arr[i];
}

arr->num -= back;
}

/** Sends to each object in arr the message identified by given selector. */
static inline void ccArrayMakeObjectsPerformSelector(ccArray *arr, SEL sel)
{
for( NSUInteger i = 0; i < arr->num; i++)
    [arr->arr[i] performSelector:sel];
}

static inline void ccArrayMakeObjectsPerformSelectorWithObject(ccArray *arr, SEL sel, id object)
{
for( NSUInteger i = 0; i < arr->num; i++)
    [arr->arr[i] performSelector:sel withObject:object];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark ccCArray for Values (c structures)

typedef ccArray ccCArray;

static inline void ccCArrayRemoveAllValues(ccCArray *arr);

/** Allocates and initializes a new C array with specified capacity */
static inline ccCArray* ccCArrayNew(NSUInteger capacity) {
if (capacity == 0)
    capacity = 1; 

ccCArray *arr = (ccCArray*)malloc( sizeof(ccCArray) );   
arr->num = 0;
arr->arr =  (id*) malloc( capacity * sizeof(id) );    // Arc Issue
arr->max = capacity;

return arr;
}

/** Frees C array after removing all remaining values. Silently ignores nil arr. */
static inline void ccCArrayFree(ccCArray *arr)
{
if( arr == nil ) return;

ccCArrayRemoveAllValues(arr);

free(arr->arr);
free(arr);
}

/** Doubles C array capacity */
static inline void ccCArrayDoubleCapacity(ccCArray *arr)
{
ccArrayDoubleCapacity(arr);
}

/** Increases array capacity such that max >= num + extra. */
static inline void ccCArrayEnsureExtraCapacity(ccCArray *arr, NSUInteger extra)
{
ccArrayEnsureExtraCapacity(arr,extra);
}

/** Returns index of first occurence of value, NSNotFound if value not found. */
static inline NSUInteger ccCArrayGetIndexOfValue(ccCArray *arr, void* value)
{
for( NSUInteger i = 0; i < arr->num; i++)
    if( arr->arr[i] == value ) return i;
return NSNotFound;
}

/** Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether value is present in the C array. */
static inline BOOL ccCArrayContainsValue(ccCArray *arr, void* value)
{
return ccCArrayGetIndexOfValue(arr, value) != NSNotFound;
}

/** Inserts a value at a certain position. Behaviour undefined if aray doesn't have enough capacity */
static inline void ccCArrayInsertValueAtIndex( ccCArray *arr, void *value, NSUInteger index)
{
NSCAssert( index < arr->max, @"ccCArrayInsertValueAtIndex: invalid index");

NSUInteger remaining = arr->num - index;

// last Value doesn't need to be moved
if( remaining > 0) {
    // tex coordinates
    memmove( &arr->arr[index+1],&arr->arr[index], sizeof(void*) * remaining );
}

arr->num++; 
arr->arr[index] = (id) value;
}

/** Appends an value. Bahaviour undefined if array doesn't have enough capacity. */
static inline void ccCArrayAppendValue(ccCArray *arr, void* value)
{
arr->arr[arr->num] = (id) value;
arr->num++;
}

/** Appends an value. Capacity of arr is increased if needed. */
static inline void ccCArrayAppendValueWithResize(ccCArray *arr, void* value)
{
ccCArrayEnsureExtraCapacity(arr, 1);
ccCArrayAppendValue(arr, value);
}

/** Appends values from plusArr to arr. Behaviour undefined if arr doesn't have
enough capacity. */
static inline void ccCArrayAppendArray(ccCArray *arr, ccCArray *plusArr)
{
for( NSUInteger i = 0; i < plusArr->num; i++)
    ccCArrayAppendValue(arr, plusArr->arr[i]);   //ARC Casting Rules
}

/** Appends values from plusArr to arr. Capacity of arr is increased if needed. */
static inline void ccCArrayAppendArrayWithResize(ccCArray *arr, ccCArray *plusArr)
{
ccCArrayEnsureExtraCapacity(arr, plusArr->num);
ccCArrayAppendArray(arr, plusArr);
}

/** Removes all values from arr */
static inline void ccCArrayRemoveAllValues(ccCArray *arr)
{
arr->num = 0;
}

/** Removes value at specified index and pushes back all subsequent values.
Behaviour undefined if index outside [0, num-1].
@since v0.99.4
*/
static inline void ccCArrayRemoveValueAtIndex(ccCArray *arr, NSUInteger index)
{   
for( NSUInteger last = --arr->num; index < last; index++)
    arr->arr[index] = arr->arr[index + 1];
}

/** Removes value at specified index and fills the gap with the last value,
 thereby avoiding the need to push back subsequent values.
 Behaviour undefined if index outside [0, num-1].
 @since v0.99.4
 */
static inline void ccCArrayFastRemoveValueAtIndex(ccCArray *arr, NSUInteger index)
{
NSUInteger last = --arr->num;
arr->arr[index] = arr->arr[last];
}

/** Searches for the first occurance of value and removes it. If value is not found the function has no effect.
 @since v0.99.4
 */
static inline void ccCArrayRemoveValue(ccCArray *arr, void* value)
{
NSUInteger index = ccCArrayGetIndexOfValue(arr, value);
if (index != NSNotFound)
    ccCArrayRemoveValueAtIndex(arr, index);
}

/** Removes from arr all values in minusArr. For each Value in minusArr, the first matching instance in arr will be removed.
 @since v0.99.4
 */
static inline void ccCArrayRemoveArray(ccCArray *arr, ccCArray *minusArr)
{
for( NSUInteger i = 0; i < minusArr->num; i++)
    ccCArrayRemoveValue(arr, minusArr->arr[i]);  //ARC Casting Rules
}

/** Removes from arr all values in minusArr. For each value in minusArr, all matching instances in arr will be removed.
 @since v0.99.4
 */
static inline void ccCArrayFullRemoveArray(ccCArray *arr, ccCArray *minusArr)
{
NSUInteger back = 0;

for( NSUInteger i = 0; i < arr->num; i++) {
    if( ccCArrayContainsValue(minusArr, arr->arr[i]) ) //ARC Casting Rules {
        back++;
    } else
        arr->arr[i - back] = arr->arr[i];
}

arr->num -= back;
}
#endif // CC_ARRAY_H
```

Comment: Not enough info - what are the definitions/types of children_ and item?

Comment: Post the code from your `CCMenu.m` that applies to your question.

Comment: please read the update on the question which includes the code.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using a version of cocos2d that isn't compatible with ARC because the ccArray code is missing the ARC fixes and additions. [Upgrade to cocos2d 1.1 or newer](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/05/update-cocos2d-iphone-existing-project/). Cocos2d 1.0.1 might work as well but I think that version still has some ARC issues.

Or [start with a fresh, ARC-enabled cocos2d project](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/) and then re-add your code and resources to it.

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix:

Get rid of this “use a raw C-array to store objects”-approach altogether and delete the whole file containing the macros.

Replace it with proper use of (mutable) containers from the Foundation framework, and move on.