# How to add objects to CCArray from a different class with ARC

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I needed to convert  my code to ARC. I have an CCArray that I use to draw a path. I fill the objects of CCArray values from a different class.

Problem is after converting to ARC, CCArray returns always `null`

I can not see what I am doing wrong.

Ladybug.h

```
@interface Ladybug : CCSprite <CCTargetedTouchDelegate>{

    CCArray *linePathPosition;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) CCArray *linePathPosition;

@end
```

Ladybug.m

```
@synthesize linePathPosition;

-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init] )) {
        self.linePathPosition = [[CCArray alloc] init];

    }
    return self;
}
-(void) updatePosition:(CGPoint) position
{
    [self.linePathPosition addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:position]];
    NSLog(@"line path %@",linePathPosition);
}
-(void) breakMoveLadyBug
{
    [self.linePathPosition removeAllObjects];
}
```

In main .m

```
- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    Ladybug *ladybug1 = (Ladybug *)[self getChildByTag:99];
    CCMotionStreak* streak = (CCMotionStreak *)[self getChildByTag:999];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    CGPoint curPosition = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];

    if (ladybug1.isSelected) {

        streak.position = curPosition;
        [ladybug1 updatePosition:curPosition];
                NSLog(@"Cur position %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(curPosition));

        if (!ladybug1.isMoving) {

            [ladybug1 startMoveLadyBug];
        }
    }
}
```

Log:

```
 Cur position {331, 110}
 line path (null)
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the proper way to define and init CCArray with ARC?

Comment: I do not see NSArray in the code you provided.

Comment: @bbarnhart CCArray sorry edited topic and question

Comment: where do you initialize your LadyBug object?

Comment: @ColdLogic bug.m is Ladybug.m I init CCArray with `self.linePathPosition = [[CCArray alloc] init]`

Comment: no, I see where you init your linePathPosition object, where do you call `[[Ladybug alloc] init]`?

Comment: @ColdLogic no where I do not call `[[Ladybug alloc] init]`  I only call `Ladybug *ladybug1 = (Ladybug *)[self getChildByTag:99]` then I use ladybug1 for calling Ladybug methods

Comment: If you never call the init function, then that array is never being allocated. To confirm, `NSLog("ladybug = %@", self);` before your `NSLog(@"line path %@",linePathPosition);` If your Ladybug object isn't null, I am willing to bet it is just a CCNode object

Comment: You are right I need to alloc init object first. If I add `Ladybug *ladybug1 = [[Ladybug alloc] init];` it  adds objects to CCArray but if I alloc I cant call `ladybug1 = (Ladybug *)[self getChildByTag:99];`

Comment: You want to have possibility to get child by tag? How about set this tag to this child? Create your ladybug and add it with tag to the parent. Then you will be able to get it with getChildByTag:.

Comment: @Morion at init of layer I do `[self addChild:ladybug1 z:999 tag:99];` so I want to get the object with tag 99 in running scene.

Comment: you add in init method of some LAYER. and trying to get it from SCENE. you can get child only from it's parent

Comment: what version of Cocos2d are you using? this OP has a similar question  that could interest you at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231431/updating-to-arc-errors

Comment: Use NSMutableArray. I wouldn't recommend using CCArray with ARC code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a problem with ARC or CCArray. The problem enlies in your understanding of objective-c.

To solve your problem, where ever you are doing this line `[self addChild:ladybug1 z:999 tag:99]`. Do this instead:

```
Ladybug *ladybug1 = [[Ladybug alloc] init];
[self addChild:ladybug1 z:0 tag:99];
```

Note: this is done outside of the `ccTouchMoved` function, in some function that adds the ladybug objects to the scene/layer.

Then your `ccTouchMoved` function will have an allocated ladybug object to work with.

The problem being that if you never call the init function on a ladybug object, the CCArray will never get allocated so everything will be null. You will then try to add points to an null array, and that will do nothing. You can do all this tag stuff you want (I personally have no idea why you are doing that), but you need to specify the tag for the ladybug object. So add it to the CCLayer/CCScene (w/e you are using), and set its tag. Then you can use the `getChildByTag` function.